# Using the "in" operator in pandas.DataFrame without getting "ambiguous error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset, boolean-expression

I have a `pd.DataFrame`

```py
import pandas as pd
country = ['US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK', 'UK']
year = ['1990', '1991', '2020', '1990', '1991', '2020']
people = [20, 34, 456, 5, 7, 300]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(country, year, people), columns = ['country', 'year', 'people'])
```

```
country year    people
0   US  1990    20
1   US  1991    34
2   US  2020    456
3   UK  1990    5
4   UK  1991    7
5   UK  2020    300
```

I wish to locate year '2020' and '1990'.
I understand that this can be achieved with:

```py
df.loc[(df.year == '2020') | (df.year == '1990')]
```

or

```py
df.query('year == [\'2020\', \'1990\']')
```

to get the output:

```
country year    people
0   US  1990    20
2   US  2020    456
3   UK  1990    5
5   UK  2020    300
```

However, I'd like to perform this 'query' with the `in` operator.
Trying:

```py
df.loc[df['year'] in ['2020', '1990']]
```

which raises the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I expect to use the `in` operator in my `pandas.DataFrame` subsetting, as it requires the least amount of typing.

What is the best way to mitigate this error raised by the `in` operator?

Comment: df.loc[df['year'].isin(['2020', '1990'])]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df[df['year'].isin(['1990','2020'])]
```

or

```
df.loc[df['year'].isin(['1990','2020'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the .isin() function.

`df.loc[df['year'].isin(['1990','2020'])]`

You input a list of options that you want 'year' to be, and pandas will return a series of boolean values. That series will in turn be interpreted by the .loc() to return only the rows where df['year'] == the desired values.